# Creating function via string in Excel

Tags: string, excel, function, statistics

I am trying to find an easier way to calculate the following stats: average, std, min, and max. So far I have tried combining the function name (E9), start column ($E$6), Start row ($F$2), end column($G$6), and end row ($F$3). The result was `AVERAGE(A2:C10)`. I want this to return the value of `AVERAGE(A2:C10)`, which is `6.23`. Is there anyway to turn this into an equation that Excel can recognize? This concept will be used to find the average, std, min, and max for a large dataset. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: As noted by @pnuts, the cell range can be constructed but not the function. To do something like that, write a *User Defined Function* (aka *UDF*) in VBA that builds the string and uses `Application.Evaluate(<your full formula string here>)` to generate the actual processing.

Comment: @pnuts - Odder still, I had an epiphany after reading your last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some thinking about this, you could build a cross-reference table that provided the functionality of the formula with `SUBTOTAL` while using `INDIRECT` to provide the range.

```
Function   Function_Num   Function_Num (excludes hidden values)
Average    1              101
Min        5              105
StDev      7              107
```

A full list of available functionality with the [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af). With that table in X1:Z4 your constructed formula would be,

=subtotal(vlookup(E9, X:Z, 2, false), indirect(e6&f3&":"&g6&f3))

Note that not every native worksheet function is available within **SUBTOTAL** but the three you have specified are as well as several others.

**Addendum:**

1. A data Validation list could use the *Source:* list for E9:G9 as X2:X4 or a named range defined as `='Sheet1'!$X$2:INDEX('Sheet1'!$X:$X, MATCH("zzz", 'Sheet1'!$X:$X))` for a 'last alphabetic' lookup.
2. The data lookup range itself could be defined as a dynamic named range with a *Source:* of `=Sheet1!$X$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$Z:$Z, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet1!$Z:$Z))` for a 'last numeric' lookup.
3. The <100 and >100 *function_num* identifiers both work the same on rows 'hidden' by the Data ► Sort & Filter ► Filter command.
4. For Excel 2010 and higher, the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-991C9ADC-88DC-4AB9-9FBF-04346623D79D) may provide additional functionality.

Comment: That's a creative use of SUBTOTAL.  I will have to remember that one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wander into the world of undocumented "features" you can use the EVALUATE function if it is defined in a named range.  It mostly works in Excel 2013 as advertised here: http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/evaluate-function.html.

The downside is that it appears it does not update unless the underlying formula or the result cell is updated.  It does not properly respond to changes in the data in the AVERAGE/SUM on their own.  This might not be an issue if you're changing the formula often (or using indirect with it since I believe INDIRECT forces full recalcs).

[image: EVALUATE in action]